# Count specific semi-consequtive subsets of a set - general formula?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a set of consequtive integer numbers {1,2,3,...36} and considering all 376992 5-number combinations out of this set, how can we count following:

number of 5-number combinations having 3 numbers like this

1. +1, +2 pattern: (1,2,4) or (2,3,5) or ... or (33,34,36)
2. +2, +2 pattern
3. +2, +3 pattern
4. +n, +k pattern

   Is it possible to generalize?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get all the subsets of 5 elements where you have 3 numbers following the pattern. 
The number of ways to get 3 numbers that follow the pattern is equal to: $$36 - n - k$$ This means that you need to figure out what is the highest value that you can pick in such a way that the second and third numbers are still in the initial set. 
From the remaining numbers, you need to pick 2, in order to form a set of 5 elements, and this can be done in: $$\binom{33}{2}$$ 
So the total number of sets that follow the rule is: 
$$(36 - n - k)  \binom{33}{2}$$

This assumes that when you have a pattern like: +2, +4, having {1,2,3,4,5} is still a valid set because {1,3,5} follow the pattern.

Comment: This is a great idea!  Unfortunately I need  +n +k pattern like this: +2, +4 pattern is {1,3,7} that is +2 is applied to smallest element, and +4 applies to the result of first +2, not to smallest element itself (1). So {1,3,5} is +2 +2 pattern, not +2 +4. Otherwise, there are no restrictions on the other (two) numbers which are not part of such 3-number-set-following-pattern.

Comment: I think `36 - n - k` is still valid. `x + n = p; p + k <= 36`. In this case `x  + n + p <= 36`. There are `36 - n - p` ways to choose x.

Comment: The formula holds only for n=1, k=1.

Comment: I don't think I follow correctly what you actually want. For `n=1;k=20` you have 36 - 21 = 15 options for the first number. (Everything from `{1,2, ..., 15}`). Last set is going to be `{15,16,36}` plus all the remaining combinations of 2 numbers out of 33. This gives 9450 possible combinations. What am I missing here ?